Wordpress WPML String translator change source String
I want to change the source string value from 'Datasheet' to 'Product Drawings' on my Wordpress website, but can't find a way to change the string.
I clicked on the View button and changed the string value to 'Product Drawings' where it showed in the PHP code, but the source string remained 'Datasheet' in WPML.
WPML view
